# Multi Environment Support in Soap UI Pro

Tags: soapui, ready-api

Soap UI Pro is very popular for **Multi Environment Support**. But, what is the use of considering it as one of the features, when we can change Environments even in Soap UI. We can simply change or add multiple endpoints in service endpoint. Is there any other facts that i am not aware about **Multi Environment Support**?

Answer (score 1):

In my test cases I typically orchestrate a series of REST and SOAP calls to multiple services and I don't want to be changing all of these by hand. But, it's not just endpoints that can change between environments: there are database settings and all types of custom properties. For even a moderately complex test case or suite, there could be dozens of things that change between environments.